# The difference between Clausal Apposition and Content Clauses

Tags: appositives

In *Cambridge Grammar of English: A Comprehensive Guide (Ronald Carter, Michael McCarthy - p. 576)* they provide this example for showing the possibility of using a finite clause as apposition to a noun phrase:

[image]

But in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Rodney Huddleston, Geoffrey K. Pullum - p. 1358)*, under the title of **Content clauses**, they provide the following example:

> [24] i : The excuse he gave – that the train had been late – seemed to satisfy
> the boss.

Under the above mentioned example, they make a distinction between a *Content clause* and an *apposition*:

[image]

Is there really a difference between the examples provided in each book or is it just matter of using a different terminology/framework?

Comment: Can an answer be an excuse? Does it not rather detail/provide an excuse? I prefer CGEL's sentence (where, note, deleting 'The excuse he gave' doesn't leave a totally satisfactory residue).

Comment: Posting images of text is generally frowned upon here. Any chance you'd type those out instead? It makes them searchable, and accessible to anyone not using a standard web browser.

Comment: Don't worry about the terminology in CGEL. It's non-standard and inconsistent, and not many linguists use it, for that reason. This sounds like another distinction not worth distinguishing.

Comment: Sour grapes again, JL? The terminology in CGEL **is** perfectly consistent. As one would expect, CGEL is spot-on here, but then it's the most accurate grammar English ever written, so one would expect it to be.

Comment: CGEL also discusses this on p448: appositives vs complements.

Comment: @BillJ vouches for its consistency, so it's all right. Whatever it means.

Comment: @BillJ 'the most accurate grammar English' : should that read 'the most accurate English grammar' ?

Comment: @JohnLawler As a non-linguist, I would be curious to know what professional linguists think about the following examples. On the one hand, [1] *She sang in the opera 'Carmen'* entails *She sang in 'Carmen'*. On the other hand, [2] *The suggestion that they cheated was quite outrageous* does **not** entail *That they cheated was quite outrageous.* Do professional linguists ever make use of this distinction, for example to distinguish dependents like *Carmen* in [1] from dependents like *that they cheated* in [2]? (These examples do happen to come from CGEL, but hopefully that doesn't matter.)

Comment: @linguisticturn I'm not sure what distinction you're asking about. Entailment is not part of grammar; it's pragmatics and semantics (to whatever extent one wants to separate the two).  _The opera 'Carmen'_ is a noun phrase followed by an apposition, whereas _the suggestion that they cheated_ is a noun phrase modified by an NP complement clause. They're already distinguished by their syntax; considering entailment seems unnecessary, especially since we don't know **why** the entailments work this way.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you!